# error on removing divs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add 3 fields dynamically (2 text fields and 1 remove button) per row. The add button is working fine. The problem is the remove function. When I add 2 fields or more, and I try to remove the first, both added fields/rows are deleted

This is my html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">

    <div class="field_wrapper form-group col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="id[]" value="" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button btn btn-primary" title="Add field">Adicionar Valor</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper:last'); //Input field wrapper
    var wrapper_delete = $('.field_wrapper');

    //var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger2" title="Remove field">Remover</a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="field_wrapper form-group col-sm-12"><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="" class="form-control"/></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" class="form-control"/></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger2" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        wrapper = $('.field_wrapper:last'); //Input field wrapper
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            var count = $('.field_wrapper').length;
            fieldHTML = '<div class="field_wrapper form-group col-sm-12"><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="id_'+ count +'" value="" class="form-control"/></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="name_' + count +'" value="" class="form-control"/></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger2" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div></div>'; //New input field html
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html

        }
    });

    $(wrapper_delete).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        wrapper_delete = $('.field_wrapper');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.field_wrapper').remove();
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the new `field_wrapper` element to `field_wrapper:last`. You should place it *after*, so instead of `.append()` you should use `.after()`.

```
$(wrapper).after(fieldHTML); // Add field html
```

And delegate click event on `document` (or closest **static** ancestor), because `.field_wrapper` element is also dynamicaly added and you can't attach event to it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhw5fv2/)</kbd>

---

Looking at what you're trying to do. I'd recommend to use [**`.clone([with events])`**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). You don't actually need to change `input` names (unless the reason is other than avoiding name duplicates), as they are set to *arrays*.
This way, all your code could be as simple as below:

```
$('.add_button').click(function(){
  $('.field_wrapper').length >= maxField ||
    wrapper.clone(true).find('a.btn').toggle().end().insertAfter('.field_wrapper:last');
});

$('.remove_button').hide().click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.field_wrapper').remove();
});

var maxField = 10, wrapper = $('.field_wrapper').clone(true);
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m2ks1rzu/)</kbd>